# request.cookies is undefined when using Supertest

Tags: cookies, nestjs, supertest

I'm passing my authentication token via an HTTP-Only cookie in my NestJS API.

As such, when writing some E2E tests for my Auth endpoints, I'm having an issue with cookies not being where I expect them.

Here's my pared-down test code:

```
describe('auth/logout', () => {
  it('should log out a user', async (done) => {
    // ... code to create user account

    const loginResponse: Response = await request(app.getHttpServer())
                                              .post('/auth/login')
                                              .send({ username: newUser.email, password });

    // get cookie manually from response.headers['set-cookie']
    const cookie = getCookieFromHeaders(loginResponse);

    // Log out the new user
    const logoutResponse: Response = await request(app.getHttpServer())
                                            .get('/auth/logout')
                                            .set('Cookie', [cookie]);

  });
});
```

In my JWT Strategy, I'm using a custom cookie parser. The problem I'm having is that `request.cookies` is always `undefined` when it gets to the parser. However, the cookie will be present in `request.headers`.

I'm following the manual cookie example from this Medium article: https://medium.com/@juha.a.hytonen/testing-authenticated-requests-with-supertest-325ccf47c2bb, and there don't appear to be any other methods available on the request object to set cookies.

If I test the same functionality from Postman, everything works as expected. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using Fastify? If so you need to register FastifyCookies still when creating the testing application.

Comment: No, I'm not suing Fastify

Answer (score 11):

I know this is an old thread but...

I also had req.cookies undefined, but for a different reason.

I'm testing my router independently, not the top level app. So I bootstrap the app in beforeEach and add the route to test.

I was getting req.cookies undefined because express 4 requires the cookieParser middleware to be present to parse the cookies from the headers.

E.g.

```js
const express           = require('express');
const bodyParser        = require('body-parser');
const cookieParser      = require('cookie-parser');
const request           = require('supertest');

const {router}  = require('./index');

describe('router', () => {
    let app;    
    
    beforeAll(() => {        
        app  = express();
        app.use(bodyParser.json());
        app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
        app.use(cookieParser());
        app.use('/', router);
    });

    beforeEach(() => jest.clearAllMocks());

    it('GET to /', async () => {
        const jwt = 'qwerty-1234567890';
        
        const resp = await request(app)
            .get('/')
            .set('Cookie', `jwt=${jwt};`)
            .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
            .send({});        
    });
    
});
```

Testing this way allows me to unit test a router in isolation of the app. The req.cookies turn up as expected.

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply, I've been out sick for a while. Thank you very much for the post, I'll have to give that a try.

Answer (score 3):

Late but I hope I can help you. The problem is in the initialization of the app object. Probably in your main.ts file you have some middlewares configured as they are: CORS and queryParse. You must also put them in your tests when you create the app.

```js
const moduleFixture: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({ 
  imports: [AppModule]
}).compile();

const app = moduleFixture.createNestApplication();

// Add CORS
app.enableCors({ credentials: true, origin: ['http://localhost:4200'] });

// Add cookie parser
app.use(cookieParser());

await app.init();
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the article you're following, the code at https://medium.com/@juha.a.hytonen/testing-authenticated-requests-with-supertest-325ccf47c2bb :
1)  has the 'cookie' value in `.set('cookie', cookie)` in lowercase and in your code it's in Pascal case ==> ***Have you tried with lowercase in your code instead ?***
2) the cookie value assigned to the 'cookie' header is not an array, whereas in your code you're assigning an array ==> ***Have you tried with a non array value ?***

So to resume, can you try with the following code:

```js
describe('auth/logout', () => {
  it('should log out a user', async (done) => {
    // ... code to create user account

    const loginResponse: Response = await request(app.getHttpServer())
                                              .post('/auth/login')
                                              .send({ username: newUser.email, password });

    // get cookie manually from response.headers['set-cookie']
    const cookie = getCookieFromHeaders(loginResponse);

    // Log out the new user
    const logoutResponse: Response = await request(app.getHttpServer())
                                            .get('/auth/logout')
                                            .set('cookie', cookie) // <== here goes the diff
                                            .expect(200, done);

  });
});
```

Let us know if that helps :)

Comment: Hello. My apologies for the very late response. Yes, I did previously try lowercasing the value and using a non-array value, but the cookie still ended up as a header instead of in the `request.cookies` collection. To work around this, I added an extractor to pull the token from the header as a fallback in my Passport strategy.